Date showing in letter format in stead of number for mui date picker
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterMoment}>
      <Box className="datePickerCustom">
        <DatePicker
          // label="Seleccione Fecha de nacimiento"
          sx={{
            '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
              '& fieldset': {
                border: 'none',
              },
              '& input': {
                height: '50px',
                padding: '0 14px',
              },
            },
            '& .MuiInputBase-input': {
              height: '50px',
              padding: '0 14px',
            },
          }}
          value={field.value || null}
          onChange={handleChange}
          renderInput={() => <input {...props} />}
          inputFormat="DD-MM-YYYY"
          className="form-control font-hyundaiHead"
        />
      </Box>
    </LocalizationProvider>

The code is working properly in the local environment and in the production environment too. But one of my user got the following weird issue while choosing a date:

The website is build for the mexican users and this issue is faced by a user from mexico. I could not reproduce the issue. It is working as expected for me in my machine.
